# How to set a checkbox value inside a model variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I'm new on rails and I'm looking for a way to store the value of my check_box_tag inside my model file.

I've tried to use params, but it's not available inside the models.

Example:

View.rb

```
<%= check_box_tag "mail_checker_issue", 1, true %>
```

Model.rb

```
@x = check_box_value???
```

Comment: Since you're interacting with the controller at that point, you'd do it in the controller. Or name it the name of the persisted property like is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you get the object to which you want to set your value, then assign it.
Something like

```
your_model_instance.setMailCheckerIssue(params[:mail_checker_issue])
```

In your model

```
def setMailCheckerIssue(val)
 @x = val
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The params are only available inside a controller. This would be the place to extract the value the user has submitted, and then maybe store it in a model object.